# Ionic 4 - Trying to adding headers to post - post call not accepting options

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to send headers with my post, and I can't seem to get a valid value in for the options.

````
  sendPostRequest() {
    let token = this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    headers.append('responseType', 'text');
    let postData = this.signatureForm.value;
    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:3000/signature", postData, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.presentToast();
      }, error => {
    });
  }

I'm getting an error in my editor on ```{ headers: headers }```
Error message is:
````

> No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following
>   error.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>         Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.ts(2769) http.d.ts(2431, 9): The expected type comes from property 'headers'
>   which is declared here on type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header:
>   string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams |
>   { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean;
>   responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }' http.d.ts(2430,
>   5): The last overload is declared here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                                 .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                                 .set('responseType', 'text')
                                 .set('Authorization',  'Bearer ' + token);

this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:3000/signature", postData, { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.presentToast();
  }, error => {
});
```

Comment: It's sending the header values, however for my token, I'm just getting "authorization":"Bearer [object Promise]"

Comment: show `console.log(token)`, I guess this is an object, to have to take string out of it

Comment: I think its working as it should, I'm getting the values in my headers.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the interface `Headers` you need to use `HttpHeaders` from `@angular/common/http'`

*Example:*

`import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

```
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json'); 
//append more stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be inside the `httpOptions`. You can modify your headers like,

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Accept': 'application/json '
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'responseType': 'text',
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token  
      });
    }



this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:3000/signature", postData, httpOptions)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.presentToast();
      }, error => {
    });
```